# Firebase functions with custom domain not working

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I use Firebase hosting and Firebase functions.
I want both to be accessible from the same domain:

`HOSTING: https://xxxxxxxxx-dev.web.app/`
`FUNCTIONS: https://xxxxxxxxx-dev.web.app/app`

Following the documentation I got this:

index.ts (Firebase function)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// etc...

app.use(cors);
app.use(cookieParser(MY_SECRET_VALUE));
app.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);

app.post('/createPromo', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  // etc...
  res.json({ success: true, error: null, data });
});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

firebase.json (in the react app)

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/app",
        "function": "app"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

api.js (in the react app)

```
const response = await fetch(`https://xxxxxxxxx-dev.web.app/api/createPromo`, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
});
```

When I call this endpoint from the app I got an HTML file with this text:
`You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.`
I can see from the logs that the firebase function is never triggered.

If instead of `"source": "/app"` I write `"source": "/app/**"` I got a **404 error not found**.

If I call the function from the original domain `https://us-central1-xxxxxxxxx-dev.cloudfunctions.net`, it works

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your express route needs to match the full path from the URL, no matter what your hosting configuration might be for it.  That means you need to include the "/app" prefix.

```
app.post('/app/createPromo', ...)
```